# Files added manually to PhpStorm not uploading

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm to develop Magento website. I have created few files and folders externally, i.e. I used `modman` to add a module from the terminal, which created some folders and files on my local machine.

Now I see this folders in the local tree. I have enabled "upload external changes" but still PhpStorm is not uploading these to my remote server. Only if I open any file which modman created and save, this will upload.

Comment: As a guess, have you tried File->Invalidate Caches / Restart? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: BTW -- when did you enable that option -- after making those files or before? If after -- you will have to manually sync local to remote first.

Comment: I enabled after adding it. This is the issue. Thanks for the info.